# printing linked list with Node contains void pointer

Tags: c

Im a beginner in c and i need to print a linked list contents but the printing function doesnt work and i dont know why. i checked if the function of creating the linked list works by printf some words after using addFirst function and it seems the addFirst function works and the  linked list has been created but the printing function doesnt
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef enum msgtag {
  NoTag = 0, Important, Work, Personal, ToDo, Later
} msgtag;

typedef struct MsgID
{
  char* id ;
} MsgID;
typedef struct MsgDetails
{
  char* id;
  msgtag tag;
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
} MsgDetails;

typedef struct Node
{
  void *item;
  struct Node* next;
} Node;
Node* addFirst(MsgDetails*ptr,Node* head) {
    Node* newHead = ( Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newHead->item = malloc(sizeof(MsgDetails));
    ((MsgDetails*)newHead->item)->year = ptr->year;
    ((MsgDetails*)newHead->item)->day = ptr->day;
    ((MsgDetails*)newHead->item)->month = ptr->month;
    ((MsgDetails*)newHead->item)->id = ptr->id;
    ((MsgDetails*)newHead->item)->tag = ptr->tag;
    newHead->next = head;

    return newHead;
}
void printAll(Node* head) {
        Node* current = NULL;
    ((MsgDetails*)current->item)->year = ((MsgDetails*)head->item)->year;
    ((MsgDetails*)current->item)->day = ((MsgDetails*)head->item)->day;
    ((MsgDetails*)current->item)->month = ((MsgDetails*)head->item)->month;
    ((MsgDetails*)current->item)->id = ((MsgDetails*)head->item)->id;
    ((MsgDetails*)current->item)->tag = ((MsgDetails*)head->item)->tag;



    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%s",((MsgDetails*)current->item)->tag,((MsgDetails*)current->item)->year,((MsgDetails*)current->item)->month,((MsgDetails*)current->item)->day,((MsgDetails*)current->item)->id);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main()

{
    Node* head = NULL;
    MsgDetails details;
    MsgDetails *ptr =NULL;
    int msg_tag;
    details.id =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
    ptr = &details;
    printf("\nenter msg metadata (tag,year,month,day,id):");
    scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%s",&msg_tag,&(details.year),&(details.month),&(details.day),details.id);
    
    details.tag = msg_tag;
    head = addFirst(ptr,head);
   
    printAll(head);

}
```

Comment: Why is your print function performing *any* assignment whatsoever beyond the pointer itself being used to walk the list? That's a [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) moment if ever there was one. Aside, `head` and `current` should *both* be const in that function; leave no doubt the purpose is *not* mutable.

Comment: Substitute the first 6 lines for ```Node* current = head;```

Comment: You can use [`memcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) to copy structures. Will make the code much cleaner.
Also from the listing above it is not obvious what's the reason behind using `void *` in `Node` structure. As it is right now it only results in all these type casts littering the code.

Comment: i use the void pointer as i want to create 2 linked list one of type MsgDetails and the other of type MsgID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code initialises `current` to (Node *)NULL, then attempts to dereference the pointer. That's not going to work.

```
void printAll(Node* head) {
        Node* current = NULL;
    ((MsgDetails*)current->item)->year = ((MsgDetails*)head->item)->year;
```

The preliminary code that makes assignments to `current` do not seem necessary. Assign `head` to `current` and it will work:

```
void printAll(Node* head) {
    Node* current = head;

    while (current) {
        printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%s", ((MsgDetails*)current->item)->tag,((MsgDetails*)current->item)->year,((MsgDetails*)current->item)->month,((MsgDetails*)current->item)->day,((MsgDetails*)current->item)->id);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @AhmedSaad: great. Why were you making all those assignments at the beginning of the print function?

Comment: i was just confused but yes it works without doing these assignments

Comment: i wanted also to ask if its possible to read the enum as intger variable without trying to define a new int variable and then assign it to details,tag?
like that 
```
scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%s",&details.tag,&(details.year),&(details.month),&(details.day),details.id);
```